# Android startActivityForResult returning result code on BackPressed event

Tags: java, android

I wrote a standard `SettingsActivity`. I need to check for a given settings after the *Activity* is *closed*. The typical event triggered on standard `SettingsActivity` closing is the `onBackPressed` event.
This my code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_CODE, intent);
    finish();
}
```

The SettingsActivity is opened in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, SettingsActivity.RESULT_CODE);
```

And this's the code that checks for the activity to *return*:

```
if((requestCode == SettingsActivity.RESULT_CODE) && (resultCode == SettingsActivity.RESULT_CODE)) 
{
    if(settings.control_mode == ControlMode.GCS)
    {
        settings.getSettings(this);
        selectController(getString(R.string.gcs_controller_id));
        settings.storeSettings(this);
    }
}
```

`requestCode` is correctly set but `resultCode` is always zero I think because I'm setting it trough `onBackPressed` event handler but I don't know how to make it in a different way. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: try removing the 'super.onBackPressed()' call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `super.onBackPressed();` . That already finishes the current activity